# Labels/points colored by category with PCA

Tags: r, plot

I'm using `prcomp` to do PCA analysis in R, I want to plot my PC1 vs PC2 with different color text labels for each of the two categories,
I do the plot with:

```
plot(pca$x, main = "PC1 Vs PC2", xlim=c(-120,+120), ylim = c(-70,50))
```

then to draw in all the text with the different colors I've tried:

```
text(pca$x[,1][1:18],  pca$[,1][1:18],  labels=rownames(cava), col="green", 
     adj=c(0.3,-0.5))
text(pca$x[,1][19:35], pca$[,1][19:35], labels=rownames(cava), col="red", 
     adj=c(0.3,-0.5))
```

But R seams to plot 2 numbers over each other instead of one, the pcs$x[,1][1:18] plots the correct points I know because if I use that plot the points it works and produces the same plot as plot(`pca$x`).

It would be great if any could help to plot the labels for the two categories or
even plot the points different color to make it easy to differentiate between the plots easily.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your x and y coordinates a bit differently:

```
text(pca$x[1:18,1], pca$x[1:18,2] ...)
```

This means take the first 18 rows and the first column (which is PC1) for the x coord, etc.
I'm surprised what you did doesn't throw an error.

If you want the points themselves colored, you can do it this way:

```
plot(pca$x, main = "PC1 Vs PC2", col = c(rep("green", 18), rep("red", 18)))
```

Comment: cool Thanks for the point color method I'll use that. The way I was sub-scripting was working (R 2.15.2) now I've just noticed they are plotting over each other because the points are the same. Thanks